# How to play sounds on Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app for Android, iOS and Windows Phone using Xamarin.forms. My question is how to play a mp3 or wav with Xamarin Forms?

My business logic is handled by Shared Project and I don't know how to use platform specifically "MediaPlayer".

Comment: Newer answer: [Xamarin Community Toolkit MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just finished creating an AudioManager for Xamarin that works on iOS, Android, UWP, Windows 8.1, and Windows Phone 8.1. If you are interested check it out at https://github.com/jcphlux/XamarinAudioManager.  There is a link to a Nuget package or feel free to clone the project.

Comment: Are you still updating your project ?

Comment: I have moved away from using Xamarin. I have been using Ionic for my mobile solutions. I have not updated it in the past 2 years. If someone want to work on an update for it I will take a pull request. Sorry.

Answer (score 16):

Right now **Xamarin.form**s has not sound **API**, so you need to use `DependencyService`

Check the following link, it is working fine for me:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088094/Playing-audio-mp-File-in-Xamarin-Forms

We would require to create an Interface which will be implemented in platform specific project, I named it as IAudio.cs and the code for the same is as follows:

```
using System;
  namespace AudioPlayEx
   {
    public interface IAudio
        {
            void PlayAudioFile(string fileName);
        }
   }
```

**Android Solution:**

```
    using System;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using AudioPlayEx.Droid;
    using Android.Media;
    using Android.Content.Res;

    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]
    namespace AudioPlayEx.Droid
    {
        public class AudioService: IAudio
        {
            public AudioService ()
            {
            }

            public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName){
                var player = new MediaPlayer();
                var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
                player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
                {
                    player.Start();
                };
                player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor,fd.StartOffset,fd.Length);
                player.Prepare();
            }
        }
}
```

**iOS Solution:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AudioPlayEx;
using AudioPlayEx.iOS;
using System.IO;
using Foundation;
using AVFoundation;

[assembly: Dependency (typeof (AudioService))]
namespace AudioPlayEx.iOS
{
    public class AudioService : IAudio
    {
        public AudioService ()
        {
        }

        public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
        {
            string sFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource
            (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
            var url = NSUrl.FromString (sFilePath);
            var _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
            _player.FinishedPlaying += (object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) => {
                _player = null;
            };
            _player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, we will use the following code in our PCL/shared project in order to play the audio file.

```
DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("MySong.mp3");
```

Comment: Tested and working.  Excellent documentation here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/

Comment: This approach doesn't work reliably. If garbage collection runs while the audio is playing, the player is destroyed and the audio abruptly stops. You can avoid the problem with a [variation of this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626548/145173) that manages player lifetime.

Answer (score 15):

You might give [`Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer`](https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/) a try, since Xamarin.Forms doesn't have a sound API.

In short, add the NuGet package to each platform-specific project you wish to support. Copy the audio files to the Assets folder for Windows UWP and Android and set the build actions as `Content` and `Android Asset` respectively. For iOS copy the audio files to the Resources folder and set the build action to `BundleResource`, then play the files like so:

```
var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current; 
player.Load("intro_sound.mp3");
player.Play();
```

Comment: By far the easiest solution.

Comment: [Updated blog link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/). [Source at github](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins).

Answer (score 6):

I think, *Xamarin.Forms has no sound APIs at the moment so you will have to write custom, platform-specific code.*

Check how **James Montemagno** implements [**TextToSpeech**](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/TextToSpeech) (using [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/))

Refer :

- [Audio Sample in Xamarin.Forms : SimpleAudioForms](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleAudioForms)
- [TextToSpeech by James Montemagno](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/TextToSpeech)

Answer (score 1):

Use a dependency service to play the sounds through the native platforms. If you only need to play one sound at a time, you can use static fields to manage the lifetime of the player objects. The static fields prevent the player from be destroyed and the audio to stop if a garbage collection occurs while the audio is playing.

The following approach plays one sound at a time, with any new sound terminating and replacing any previous sound.

Create an interface for a dependency service:

```cs
public interface IAudio {
    void PlayAudioFile(string fileName);
}
```

Use the dependency service where you want to play the sound:

```cs
DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("honk.mp3");
```

This is the dependency service for iOS:

```cs
using AVFoundation;
using Foundation;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]
public class AudioService : IAudio {
    static AVAudioPlayer player;

    public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName) {
        var url = NSUrl.FromString(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
        player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
        player.FinishedPlaying += (sender, e) => { player = null; };
        player.Play();
    }
}
```

This is the dependency service for Android:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Media;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]
public class AudioService : IAudio {
    static MediaPlayer player;

    public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName) {
        player?.Stop();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        var fd = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
        player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
        player.Prepared += (s, e) => player.Start();
        player.Completion += (s, e) => { player = null; };
        player.Prepare();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @MikeDarwish for his answer showing the native calls to use.