# Playing audio in Xamarin's main activity with MediaPlayer doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin, audio

After some research I got this code in my MainActivity.cs

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.myaudio);
player.Start();
```

And in my Resource/raw folder I have myaudio.mp3 file. No exception is being thrown and everything is build , but the song doesn't start. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41766637/4977870)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have a sub folder named raw under Resources.
2. Add the Audio file you need to play in raw folder. For example it is "MyAudio.mp3"

I do one sample according to this article, and playing audio successfully, and I don't have any issue.

Here is the article about playing audio, you can take a look:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/playing-the-audio-and-video-file-using-xamarin-android-application/

Comment: I've removed a GitHub link from this answer, since it is no longer available. If you can restore the repo, please also edit the answer to add the link back in.