# Visual Studios (Xamrin Forms) How to add sound to a button when clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, audio, xamarin.forms

I have been surfing google for a week now, yet I cant find how to play a sound when I press a button, all youtube videos give me the answer but on xamrin android or android studios. i want to do it on visual studios as I'm trying to build a piano app, and this is literally the key element I need.
ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play sounds on Xamarin.forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256176/how-to-play-sounds-on-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Put mp3 in these folders , Android Assets en iOS Recourses

[image]

Property

[image]

And iOS property
[image]

**Install this - pluging Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer**

To play in a Button.Clicked

> var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
> player.Load("Drup.mp3");
> player.Play();